# Nestable tabs doesn't behave well with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a nestable tabs but I ran into this big issue.

The tabs container has `position:absolute` and it is fine not until when I added new set of tab inside content.

The problem is that the nested div is overflowing inside the parent div.

How to fix this without adding markup or changing the markup or adding a fixed height?

Result should look like the ff image:

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 90%;
  font: normal normal 100% 'Arial',Verdana,sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  background:#eee
}

.tabs * {
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#ccc
}
ul.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}
ul.tabs > li {
  float:left;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs > li > a {
  margin-right:4px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #999;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
ul.tabs > li.active > a {
  color: #f00;
}
ul.tabs > li.active > a,
ul.tabs > li > div {
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul.tabs > li > div {
  display: none;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width:1px;
  left:0;
}
ul.tabs > li.active > div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">tab 1</a>
      <div>
        <!--content with nested tabs starts-->
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">tab 1.1</a>
            <div>
              content1
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">tab 1.2</a>
            <div>
              content2
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">tab 1.3</a>
            <div>
              content3
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--content with nested tabs ends-->
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">tab 2</a>
      <div>
        content2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">tab 3</a>
      <div>
        content3
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Lots of similar queries about this found in google but it doesn't seem to solve my issue. Maybe you can suggest a better and updated solution [FIDDLE HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/gj0qztws/2/)

Comment: I see your fiddle but it would be helpful to know just how exactly you want the end result to look.

Comment: The title says it...

Comment: The title says 'don't behave well'. That is a rather vague indicaion. There are plenty of ways to get nested tables to display, align and be styled. Just show me a diagram or sample of the desired end result and I'll gladly modify the css, or surely else someone will. But with the current lack of specificity...

Comment: I ran into this problem before, I'll try my best to solve it :)

Comment: I also don't understand what your final result is supposed to look like, can you provide a sample image of your desired result?

Comment: I can't understand why others are having a hard time understanding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is it! I did not use position absolute but float the `a` to left, float the content container to right then added margin. I did not changed the markup at all.

```css
body {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 90%;
  font: normal normal 100% 'Arial',Verdana,sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  background:#eee
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
}
.tabs * {
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#ccc
}
ul.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}
ul.tabs > li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs > li > a {
  float: left;
  margin-right:4px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #999;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
ul.tabs > li.active > a {
  color: #f00;
}
ul.tabs > li.active > a,
ul.tabs > li > div {
  background-color: #fff;
}
ul.tabs > li > div {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 37px 0 0 -100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width:1px;
  display:none
}
ul.tabs > li.active > div {
  display:block
}
```

```html
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">tab 1</a>
      <div>
        <!--content with nested tabs starts-->
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">tab 1.1</a>
            <div>
              content1
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">tab 1.2</a>
            <div>
              content2
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">tab 1.3</a>
            <div>
              content3
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--content with nested tabs ends-->
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">tab 2</a>
      <div>
        content2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">tab 3</a>
      <div>
        content3
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will make you happy.

```css
body {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 90%;
  font: normal normal 100% 'Arial',Verdana,sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  background:#eee
}

.tabs * {
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#ccc
}
ul.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}
ul.tabs > li {
  position:relative;
  float:left; 
  list-style:none;
}
ul.tabs > li > a {
  margin-right:4px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #999;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color:#ddd;
  position:relative;
}
ul.tabs > li.active > a {
  color: #f00;
}
ul.tabs > li.active > a,
ul.tabs > div {
  background-color: #fff;
}

ul.tabs > div {
  display: none;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width:1px;
  left:0;
}

ul.tabs > div.active {
    position:relative;
    width:96%;
    display: table;

}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#">tab 1</a> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">tab 3</a>
        </li>
          
        <div class="active">
              <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">tab 1.1</a> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">tab 2.1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">tab 3.1</a>
                </li>
                  
                <div class="active">
                    content1.1
                </div>
                <div>
                    content2.1
                </div>
                <div>
                    content3.1
                </div>
              </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            content2
        </div>
        <div>
            content3
        </div>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Oh it looks great on other browser but not on firefox. My main browser is firefox that's why I didn't noticed it. But I'll try to make it work based on your answer, hope it will work :)

Comment: You changed the structure of the original markup presented by the op... There is nothing wrong with the original markup, it's just about the css...